# cocos2d-x draw sprite on the sreen frame by frame

Tags: c++, textures, cocos2d-x, sprite

I have an image and I can create a Sprite from that image and `addChild` to a layer. And this image will be visible unless I have not `removedChild`. I wonder if there is a way not to `addChild`, but call some `draw` function on game loop update. And if I don't call the draw, the the image is not being drawn during that frame.

I use entity systems framework, and in each frame I want to decide if I show an image or no. But also I want to be able to manipulate the layer in which it will be drawn and the z order.

One solution is to `addChild` and manipulate `isVisible` attribute, but as far as I know it is not effective, because even thought the sprite will not be visible, anyway CPU/GPU will process it.

Comment: the visible overhead is minimal. Don't fight the engine, work with it.

Comment: What if I have thousands of objects that are addChild-ed but not visible?

Comment: Then you have thousands too many, regardless. You should look into re-using the nodes that aren't currently on-screen. For example in a tiling world you would only display the sprites on screen +1 row +1 column and when scrolling past the current boundary move the sprites from one side to the other and update their textures. If you are worried about efficiency, this is what you should look into, because frequently adding/removing nodes is far more time-consuming than changing their visible state.